# in intent in android app development using java language. error is getContext() could not be used

Tags: java, android

i could not use 'getContext()' method while working on intents.
the error is "non static method getContext() can not be referenced by static context"

[1]: http://screencast.com/t/MyQJMa323     ..this the image of my code

Comment: Use keyword `this` instead of `View.getContext()`.

Comment: don't post screenshots of code, but just copy paste the code!

Answer (score 0):

You have used 'class name' instead of the 'variable name'.

Replace

```
View.getContext()
```

with

```
v.getContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
View.getContext()
```

with

`v.getContext()`

It will work.
happy coding.